# Chrome Extension - SoundCloud Page Action

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am building a page action chrome extension and I am running into problems when I am manipulating the content on SoundCloud.  I want my extension to analyze the plays, likes, reposts, and comments for each song on the page then add additional information based on the data to each song in the feed.

The problem is that when the page loads, no sounds are loaded into the feed, instead a java script loads them in after the page load.  So when I read the document with the extension on load, there is no data to read.  Initially I worked around this by adding a delay from when the page loads to when the content script is run, but this doesn't work when the user scrolls down further and loads more songs.

Does anyone have any ideas on what I could use as an indicator to run the content scripts.  In other words what cue can I use to determine that there are new songs to analyze on the page.

Thanks

Comment: You could use content-script to inject your code into the JS functions in the original page, so that when the function (something like "play_music" I guess) is triggered, your code also runs.

Comment: Take a look at the canonical question on [DOM modification events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-jquery-dom-change-listener). This may help, if you find an appropriate element to listen for.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something somewhat similar and the solution I found was to create my own onElementInsert function and continually check until content has injected into the page.

I've altered my code a bit to try to suit your needs. It might require additional changes by you:

```
function onElementInsert( parent, func ) {
    var startingElementCount = parent.childNodes.length;

    // Checks to see if the element's number of immediate children nodes increased
    var checkChildCount = function(count) {
        if ( count < parent.childNodes.length ) {
            func();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    // Interval function to repeat every 100 milliseconds
    var interval = window.setInterval( function() {
        // Check if there are any new children
        if ( checkChildCount(startingElementCount) ) {
            // If so then trigger the insert event
            document.dispatchEvent( new Event('insertEvent') );
        }
    }, 100 );

    // Add an event listener for our insert event which will tell our interval to stop
    document.addEventListener('insertEvent', function (e) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }, false); 
}

onElementInsert( document.getElementsByClassName('lazyLoadingList')[0].childNodes[0], function() {
   // Enter code here to execute when content has been added
});
```

**So a breakdown of what's happening here:**

1. This code calls the function onElementInsert(ele, func) which will continuously check if any new children nodes are added to the element (ele) passed to it.
2. When an insert has occurred it will execute the function (func) and
   will trigger the 'insertEvent' which will tell the function to stop
   checking for further inserts.

The element with the class name 'lazyLoadingList' is the element I found that SoundCloud loads it's soundList items into. Might want to double check this for yourself.

One other thing to be aware of is that this will only check for new immediate children of the element you pass in, it won't detect children of children. So when you use it, make sure it is called on the element which is having content inserted into -- or change it to check all children.